# Check for id class type without code duplication

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to two classes which provide different functions I need to detect the class of each of it and then perform those function that results in code duplication. Is there a way to specify id ?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id player;
    -(void) checkPlayer
    {
        if ([self.player isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerController class]]){
            MPMoviePlayerController* player = (MPMoviePlayerController*) self.player;
            if (player.loadState != MPMovieLoadStateStalled || player.loadState != MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
            {
               // do something
            }
        }
        else if([self.player isKindOfClass:[MyCustomPlayerController class]]) {
            MyCustomController* player = (MyCustomPlayerController*) self.player;
            if (player.loadState != MPMovieLoadStateStalled || player.loadState != MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
            {
               // do something else
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can remove the code duplication by creating a common base class for those view controllers.  You may already have it, if one of them derives from the other.

Comment: the base class of both of these class is NSObject

Comment: Then create a common base-class.  Code duplication eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use protocols for that case. You code will be nice and clean.

Example:

```
@protocol Player
- (StateEnum)state;
@end

@interface MyCustomPlayerController <Player>
@end

@interface MPMoviePlayerController <Player>
@end


@property (nonatomic, retain) id<Player> player;
-(void) checkPlayer {
   if (self.player.state != MPMovieLoadStateStalled || self.player.state != MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thing of same but state is not the only property I need . I am using other properties of the player like [self.player pause], [self.player play], self.player.currentPlaybackduration and many more so for all of those I need to define those in the protocol right? basically all the properties of MPMediaPlayback protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminte code duplication by creating a @protocol

```
@protocol LoadStateProtocol <NSObject>

@property (assign, ...) MPMovieLoadState loadState; 

@end
```

and having both MyCustomPlayerController and MPMoviePlayerController conforming to this protocol.

```
@interface MyCustomPlayerController < LoadStateProtocol >
/* ... */
@end
```

if MPMoviePlayerController is not one of your class BUT already has the property loadState, just create a objC categorie on it in the .m file that has the checkPlayer method

```
@interface MPMoviePlayerController (LoadStateProtocol) 
< LoadStateProtocol >
@end
@implementation MPMoviePlayerController (LoadStateProtocol)
@end
```

and then you can stop checking:
just change the type of `self.player` to `id< LoadStateProtocol >`